# How do scripting language interpreters reference their underlying functions?

Tags: python, hashmap, interpreter, rhino, v8

When it comes to script interpreters, like Rhino, Google V8, Python, etc. - is there any general approach to determining the underlying native methods, given only a string of scripting language?

At some point, do these interpreters use hash maps with strings for keys? Or is there a lot of string equality testing and branches?

Comment: V8 isn't a normal interpreter in that it performs some major optimizations, skips any intermediate format, and jumps straight to low-level execution. The Python interpreter may be a better candidate if you want to learn about this.

Comment: Ralph, would you mind clarifying exactly what you mean by "fetching native methods"?

Comment: Changed "fetching" to "determining". Even with V8, there must be some point at which a string from the script (such as a method name) has to go through a hash code algorithm or be tested against other strings to determine what to do. Is this correct?

Comment: Seems like an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547792/how-do-interpreters-written-in-c-and-c-bind-identifiers-to-c-functions?rq=1

Comment: These are all informative answers, including the links to other questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They typically use hash maps with string keys, but the result of a function lookup is typically cached, to avoid having to do the exact same lookup again a few nanoseconds later.

Of course the cache must be cleared if something crazy happens, like the program assigns to or deletes the function.

JIT compilers can use [inline caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching) to make predictable function calls run very fast once the cache is populated.

The compiler can even just spit out machine code that directly calls the underlying function. Again, if the program replaces or deletes that function, the compiled code would then become invalid; so the interpreter must have a way to detect that situation and update or discard the invalid JIT code.

Answer (score 1):

CPython uses namespaces extensively for function/method dispatch, which means a hash type, AKA "dictionary".

Pypy, Jython, IronPython, etcetera may have their own thoughts about how best to do this.  Python != CPython.

Comment: CPython has a method cache where it stores method lookup results, to avoid doing the same lookup again and again in a tight loop. (Caching methods is easier in Python than in JS because more stuff is immutable.)

Answer (score 1):

For Python, when the source code is processed by the Python, all definitions (of classes and their methods, of normal functions, etc.) are compiled. The result of compilation of the parts of the code is stored as objects that capture the code. The name is stored inside only for introspection purpose -- from user point of view, the objects are unnamed. However, the name (of the class, of the function) is stored as a key in an internal hash map (called dictionary in Python). The value is the reference to the unnamed object.

Any variable in Python is the name bound to untyped reference (key, value in a hash map). Whenever a name appears in Python, you are working with a reference variable. It is automatically dereferenced via searching in the mentioned hash map (dictionary).

The user even has access to the dictionary. This way, you can try that it works this way. Then you also can easily give the function a different name (e.g. shorter) by simply assigning the function name into another variable -- assignment always means assigning the reference value.